# NUMBER type in h2 database

Tags: h2, ddl

In Oracle, I have a field of table defined as

```
NUMBER(6,0)
```

How can I define an equivalent field on a new table in H2 DB?

Comment: `NUMERIC(6, 0)`?

Comment: There are many types in h2 and I am not sure, so it's why I am asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NUMERIC seems to be the right type.

From [h2 documentation](https://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#numeric_type):

> Data type with fixed decimal precision and scale. This data type is recommended for storing currency values.
> If precision is specified, it must be from 1 to 100000. If scale is specified, it must be from 0 to 100000, 0 is default.
> See also numeric literal grammar. Mapped to java.math.BigDecimal.

Example:

> NUMERIC(20, 2)